# Blocking old versions of application to all users

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

I have an application uploaded on google play with version code , and upon making a new version  , i want to restrict the users with already old versions installed , so basically i want to disable access to old version for users who already have the old app installed and force them to use the latest version , but i could not think of a way to do that , is there anyway possible to do it , thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you already implemented logic in the old version to do a version check and disable itself, then no, this is not possible for existing old versions.

Moving forward, you could implement [in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates).